# Different error management between RHEL6 and RHEL7 when sourcing files in tcsh

Tags: tcsh, rhel7

Considering the following files on tcsh shell:

in ./foo:

```
echo $UNKNOWN_VARIABLE
```

in ./bar:

```
echo ok
```

in ./baz:

```
source ./foo ;
source ./bar
```

If I launch the command...

```
eval `cat baz`
```

...on RHEL6, I obtain the error 'UNKNOWN_VARIABLE: Undefined variable.' and the command exits with a non 0 status.

If I launch the same command on RHEL7, I obtain:

```
UNKNOWN_VARIABLE: Undefined variable.
ok
(terminal killed)
```

After further investigations regarding tcsh versions (thanks to Martin for the idea), I note a different behavior between tcsh 6.17.04 and 6.17.05.

With 6.17.04, tcsh behaves like if used with the -e option (the command stops at the first error in foo and bar is not sourced), with 6.17.05 bar is sourced (ok printed).

But there is still a difference between tcsh >= 6.17.05 I downloaded and compiled and the tcsh binary installed on my machine: the former does not crash the shell at the end and the latter is killed.

Could the signal handling be different in the 2 cases?
(I also tried to play with the onintr, hup and nohup commands without success)

Notes:

- I must use tcsh (I know it is not the best shell)
- It seems replacing ';' by '&&' in baz works fine but I prefer not to change this file.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Which tcsh versions are you using? And does running it with `tcsh -f` to prevent loading the init files help? RHEL and derivatives have the annoying habit of shipping some very non-standard configurations that can differ between releases; it sounds like `set -e` is set; you can also try using `set +e` to disable it.

Comment: As I am using login shell (without tcsh subshell), I do not see any possibility to use -f and/or +/-e options. I use tcsh 6.17.00 on RHEL6 and 6.18.01 on RHEL7.